# WebApi route not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Here is my route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "CreateUser",
   routeTemplate: "api/User/CreateUser",
   defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "CreateUser" }
);
```

Here is the endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<User> CreateUser([FromBody] User user)
{
    db.DirectUsers.Add(user);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return user;
}
```

I am sending this post data:

```
{
    "UserId" : 1
    "Name" : "Nick"
    "TwitterHandel" : "x"
}
```

To : `http://localhost:56792/api/User/CreateUser`

But im getting a 404

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you do not need to add routes for each action method. Just one route configuration is enough for normal API.

If you need advanced routing, you can look at Web API 2's attribute routing.

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    // This alone is enough.
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});

    ...
}
```

Beside, you should not access via `http://.../api/User/CreateUser`. It really defeats the purpose of using Web API in which action methods are mapped to HTTP Verbs.

So all you need is just HTTPOST to this URL for creating a new user.

http://localhost:56792/api/User/

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "CreateUser",
   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "CreateUser", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Works for the first route, adding routes after 404.